# MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried maybe 20 solutions I found in the internet none seemed to work.
Trying to connect to a xampp mysql database to input the registiration info from a flask app and it gets denied.

Code looks like this:

```
class KayitForm(Form):
name = StringField("Ad Soyad",validators=[validators.Length(min = 3,max = 20)])
username = StringField("Kullanıcı Adı",validators=[validators.Length(min = 5,max = 30)])
email = StringField("E-posta",validators=[validators.DataRequired(message="E-posta Giriniz"),validators.Email(message="Hatalı E-Posta Girdiniz")])
password = PasswordField("Parola:",validators=[
    validators.DataRequired(message="Parola Giriniz"),
    validators.EqualTo(fieldname = "confirm",message="Parolanız Uyumsuz")
])
confirm = PasswordField("Parola Doğrula")

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "localhost"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = ""
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "FlaskDeneme"
app.config["MYSQL_CURSORCLASS"] = "DictCursor"

mys = MySQL(app)


form = KayitForm(request.form)

if request.method == "POST" and form.validate():
    
    name = form.name.data
    username = form.username.data
    e_mail = form.email.data
    password = sha256_crypt.encrypt(form.password.data)
    cursor = mys.connection.cursor()

    sorgu = "insert into Users(name,email,username,password) values(%s,%s,%s,%s)"

    cursor.execute(sorgu,(name,e_mail,username,password))
    mys.connection.commit()

    cursor.close()
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you connect via something else? Is it just Python that can't connect? If it's not just Python then this is the wrong site to ask this on as that would just be a general software issue.

Comment: No I can’t connect via anything else.

Comment: Then you're telling me this has nothing to do with Python but everything to do with the xampp mysql database; meaning that you should ask this question not on a site for programming help, but general software help. StackOverflow would be potentially where you would need to ask this if it was just a Python issue, but this isn't even specific to Python at all, let alone specific Python code. StackOverflow is for getting help with code.